# Problem Cropping Images From WP Customizer

Tags: images, themes, theme-customizer

Getting the following error.

```
There has been an error cropping your image.
```

The issue happens only with this one theme, and only with the customizer. The cropped image is in the media directory, there just seems to be an issue with Wordpress receiving the successfully cropped message.

The following have been confirmed:

- Settings snippet works in TwentyFifteen theme.
- PHP GD is installed.
- Cropping images in posts works
- Creates the image, the image editor is unaware that it's successful.
- No issues are created in the log. PHP memory is set to 256MB.

Any suggestion on where to start would be very much appreciated. Thanks!